# What type of switch/IC/relay to use?

Tags: circuit-design, switches, relay, integrated-circuit, dpdt

I was wondering what I can use for S1 in the attached diagram. The switch function itself needs to be DPDT, and the operation needs to be (on)-off-(on) one way or another.

I need to trigger the switch (in whatever form) via a Raspberry Pi GPIO connection. I have found various relays that functionally fit the bill, but they don't offer (on)-off-(on) function.

The current being provided for either coil can't be sustained longer than about 8 seconds without burning them up, so the momentary function is critical.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: As you're using Raspberry Pico, you should do it by program. There's no such momentary DPDT relay.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by „(on)-off-(on)“

Comment: Use two relays with one OFF function and ON - ON for each (2 GPIO outputs). Use/add also 2 Back EMF diodes ...

Comment: Panthera, That's noting how the switch operates (or in this case needs to operate).  The parenthesis indicate a momentary action.

Comment: What about if instead of a switch or a relay, I use MOSFET transistors on either side of the coil and then connect the gates something like an LED Driver IC to trigger them?